# not equal operator doesn't return correct result sql

Tags: sql, compare, equals

I have this query there I want get all empids' who didn't not handle orders on February 12 , 
2008

```
Select Distinct E.empid, lastname, firstname 
    From HR.Employees as E
    INNER JOIN Sales.Orders as O
    ON E.empid = O.empid 
    Where O.orderdate <> Convert(datetime,'02/12/2008',101)
```

using NOT IN, EXISTS or set operators is not applicable can somebody get me a genuine solution and explanation also

Comment: Does orderdate include the time that the order was made?

Comment: What is O.orderdate? is it a datetime? If so, you will have to convert it as well, and you should be aware that will probably kill your ability to use any index on that column

Comment: @StefanH time is 00:00:00 for every entry

Comment: @user1207217 O.orderdate is column name, there Date on which order was made and yes it's type is datetime

Comment: Is it fair to assume that the order table won't have records for a specific date where an employee didn't handle the orders?

Comment: @shahkalpesh is it fair and it does so it only has records where an employee handled an order but exercise ask for it

Comment: Did the modified SQL in my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a left outer join:

```
Select Distinct E.empid, lastname, firstname 
From HR.Employees as E left outer join
     Sales.Orders as O
     ON E.empid = O.empid and O.orderdate = Convert(datetime,'02/12/2008',101)
where o.orderdate is NULL
```

If there is a match between employees and orders on the date, then the `where` clause ignores those records.

This query is rephrasing your logic.  You say "I want get all empids' who didn't not handle orders on February 12 , 2008".  The way this works is it actually matches the employees to orders on that date.  However, because it uses a `left outer join`, the match leaves a NULL when there is no match.  These are the ones that you want.

In a sense, this query answers the equivalent question, phrased as "I want all empids that fail to match an order on such-and-such a date."

Comment: can you please explain it to me more precisely even though I've understood the concept but I can't get the whole picture why didn't my query work and this did thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Select E.empid, lastname, firstname 
    From HR.Employees as E
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT O.Empid FROM Sales.Orders as O
    WHERE O.empid = E.EmpID
    AND O.orderdate = '02/12/2008')
```

EDIT: The assumption is that the Orders table will not have records of a given date for employees who didn't handle it.

```
Select E.empid, lastname, firstname, MAX(O.OrderDate) 
    From HR.Employees as E LEFT JOIN Sales.Orders as O
    ON O.empid = E.EmpID
    WHERE O.orderdate = '02/12/2008'
GROUP BY E.empid, lastname, firstname
HAVING MAX(O.OrderDate) IS NULL
```

EDIT2: I haven't tried this. I hope you get the idea of what is being done using `LEFT JOIN`, `MAX` and `HAVING`.

Comment: I don't want to use EXISTS I want to use joins only

Answer (score 0):

While doing only date comparisons you should use trunc.
Try this

```
Select Distinct E.empid, lastname, firstname 
    From HR.Employees as E
    INNER JOIN Sales.Orders as O
    ON E.empid = O.empid 
    Where trunc(O.orderdate) <> trunc(TO_DATE('02/12/2008','MM/DD/YYYY'))
```

Comment: There is no need to `trunc()` a date that has been create with `to_date()` without a time part (but it doesn't hurt either). But you should specify a format mask for the `to_date()` call, the way you have specified it, it might fail depending on NLS settings.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name-thanks. Updated my answer for the NLS format.

Answer (score 0):

For Sql-Server:

I think the problem is your `date format`. Try using ISO format (`yyyymmdd`) instead. Also since you are not having any time on the right, your `o.orderdate should be a date type field`  otherwise convert it as `convert(date,O.orderdate) <> Convert(date,'20081202')`;

```
Select Distinct E.empid, lastname, firstname 
From HR.Employees as E
INNER JOIN Sales.Orders as O
ON E.empid = O.empid 
Where convert(date,O.orderdate) <> Convert(date,'20081202')
```